# RegisterClientScriptBlock without form tag

Tags: asp.net, javascript, registerclientscriptblock

After trying to understand why client code is not rendered in a page (injected by user control) I found this [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=105002), it turns out you must have a form tag for it to work ([Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) did declare this but [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef(VS.80).aspx) which I use does not say anything regarding this).
I am using Visual studio 2005.
Does anyone know if this has been solved?

**Edit**:
To clarify, I want my control to add javascript code to the head section of the page without having to use the

```
<form runat="server"
```

I have tried adding it using:

```
HtmlGenericControl x = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
x.InnerText = "alert('123');";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(x);
```

But this did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!
My mistake was not doing it in the **OnPreRender** method (I used the **Render** method).

Now all that is needed is - like Mitchel Sellers wrote, set the header to runat server and than add to it's controls:

```
 HtmlGenericControl x = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
 x.InnerText = GetScriptSection();
 Page.Header.Controls.Add(x);
```

Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: What is GetScriptSection()

Comment: GetScriptSection is a function I used to generate the script to place into the script section control.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this functions the same in current versions, you can test it very simply though.

**Update**

per discussion in the comments, the only "workaround" that I could think of would be for your to manually insert the script into the "head" section of the page on your own, using a runat="server" declaration on the Head element.

Comment: I did test it and it does not work without the form tag. is there any work-around so I don't have to use the form runat='server' ?

Comment: Edited answer with a bit of detail.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN Page for registerclientscriptblock [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock(VS.71).aspx) says:

> The client-side script is emitted just
>   after the opening tag of the Page
>   object's <form runat= server> element.
>   The script block is emitted as the
>   object that renders the output is
>   defined, so you must include both tags
>   of the <script> element.

If you do not want to include a form, than you will basically need to build your own implementation of it.

Comment: What do you mean by "build your own implementation of it" - I have no use for the form itself, I just want the script to be added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Minor clarification for anyone seeing this:

The form tag must have the runat="server" attribute set, e.g.

`<form id="theform" runat="server">`

Just placing a regular HTML form tag in the page will not help.